# Can I use the same LLC for different business activities?

Tags: business, limited-liability-company

For example, can I use the same LLC to drive for Uber and for working on computer repairs?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. There is no strict regulation of what kind of business can be operated out of a for profit entity in most jurisdictions, subject to some specific exceptions.

In certain regulated industries, e.g. banking, pubic utilities, alcohol industry firms, firearms sales and manufacturing firms, marijuana industries, law firms, firms of medical doctors, there are limits on the scope of what can be in a single entity. But, these are exceptions to a permissive general rule.

Comment: I have a document for my LLC on sales tax and there is a line on it talking about what line of business (computer parts manufacturing) my LLC is in.  Is this relevant to this question?  Maybe it's only applicable to that particular sales tax exemption?

Comment: The expandable category listing at this site (up to six digit codes) is the level of detail that you need. http://tariffdata.wto.org/ReportersAndProducts.aspx